# Laravel view is not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, frameworks, php-5.5

i am trying to learn laravel. I am facing problem with view. while i run this following code:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return 'welcome';
});
```

It works fine. But while i tried to use view

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('welcome');
});
```

i get nothing but a blank page. (a welcome.balde.php page is exist in resource/views directory)

I also getting problem during routing. a code like this

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
```

i can't access localhost/laravel/public/home directory it gives me an error that there is no directory or file not found.
Instead of this localhost/laravel/public/index.php/home url works.
Don't know what's the problem. I am using php 5.4 and mysql 5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using linux OS, that is why having problem with permission. After giving  proper permission (apache server) to my project folder, view problem is fixed.

Comment: which folder and what permission

Answer (score 1):

view() function probably  doesn't exist. 
Try this,

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return View::make('welcome');
});
```

If this doesn't help(Check your log, stored in app/storage/logs)

Your application is in debug mode? 
You can check this in /app/config/app.php file.